# Run WCF WebService on IIS ,HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I have a WCF WebService that uses JSON format.
I can run it in Visual Studio 2013 properly but when i publish it to IIS to run by my machine local ip and a specific port (192.168.1.6:8005) to access it from local network by this address :

```
 http://192.168.1.6:8005/Service1.svc/checkLogin?username=2&password=2&code=1
```

it is the error :

```
 HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070002
Requested URL   http://192.168.1.6:8005/Service1.svc/checkLogin?kodemelli=2&password=2&bank_hesab_number=1
Physical Path   E:\testjson\Service1.svc\checkLogin
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

three files namely : Service1.svc, Web.config and JSONSample.dll are exist in physical path of its IIS Website.

here is my web.config :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Copyright ©) Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved. -->
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>    
    <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JSONSample.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="JSONSample.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="JSONSample.Service1Behavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.6:8005/Service1" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JSONSample.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="192.168.1.6"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
  </service>
</services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And a part of IService.cs :

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "checkLogin?username={username}&password={password}&code={code}")]
    string checkLogin(string username, string password, string code);
```

I read very articles and topics to solve this problem, but the problem still exist.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to browse the service page at `http://192.168.1.6:8005/Service1.svc`?

Comment: @Tim no the output : HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: What version of IIS are you deploying to? Have you enabled WCF on IIS? Basically add the HTTP Activation feature.

Comment: I posted what might be an answer.. However if you are outputing Json I have to question why you are even using WCF (Soap).  Would it not be better/easier to use WebApi and take advantage of Rest?

Comment: @Garett IIS 7.5. If you mean Install and Configure Internet Information Services from Programs and Features, yes.

Comment: @Ryios - OP is using RESTful WCF, not SOAP (though the SOAP endpoint is available).

Comment: There might be an issue with the IIS configuration for WCF.  You can try running/re-running the [ServiceModel Registration Tool (ServiceModelReg.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Ryios I have no emphasis on WCF, my main purpose is to access SQL Server database data which is on a server by this WCF web service, if you have a better/easier  way to do this ,I am pleased to do so.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, It works. please make it an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, it appears this was an issue with IIS configuration for WCF.   The [ServiceModel Registration Tool (ServiceModelReg.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012(v=vs.110).aspx) tool can be run (or re-run) to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy the physical svc file with the markup tieing it to the code?  If you just have a dll in the iis sites bin but no SVC file at the specified virtual path than you will get a 403 unless you configure the relativeAddress in the web.config's serviceActivations section.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="Service1.svc" service="YourService"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: yes, i have physical svc file, Its content : <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="JSONSample.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>