# 0x80070002 error in mvc,c#, visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I got following error when I'm running the project.
[image]

what can I do for this.hope your help with this.

Comment: Might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377673/run-wcf-webservice-on-iis-http-error-404-0-not-found

Comment: it can't find the view, however a little bit more information will do @bill